# Wait. I move the car front a bit

Tags: sentence-structure

I sent my wife to company.

We were arrived the company.

A car was stopped in front of us. So I have to stop right after it.

My wife wanted to get out of the car.

"**Wait. I move the car front a bit**." as the car has gone, I wanted to move my car to front a bit.

Does it sound natural?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you saying that you parked the car behind another car when you arrived, and the car in front of you left before you and your wife got out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Your original sentences in bold**
>   *What sounds more natural in italic.*
>
> **I sent my wife to company.**
>   *I took my wife to work.*
>
> **We were arrived the company.**
>   *We arrived at the company (work)*.
>
> **A car was stopped in front of us. So I have to stop right after it.**
>   *There was a stopped car in front of us. So I stopped behind it.*
>
> **My wife wanted to get out of the car.**
>
> **"Wait. I move the car front a bit." as the car has gone, I wanted to move my car to front a bit.**
>   *"Wait. I will move the car forward a bit."  Since the car left, I wanted to move my car forward a bit*

Comment: Or "A car stopped in front of us" for the third one (assuming "was" might have been used to translate a passive rather than a stative).

Comment: For the second sentence, I might go with, "we arrived at her workplace".